# "Plus importante que" as a comparative of a measure

Tags: sens

Why is "plus importante que ..." used to indicate a larger quantity rather than higher priority in this sentence?

> La population du Japon est plus importante que celle de Nouvelle-Zélande.

https://tatoeba.org/en/sentences/show/331179

This disagrees with all senses listed in the Trésor.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/important

Comment: Have you looked at a dictionnary?

Comment: Because the words "plus important que" or "moins important que" in French also mean a larger number than or a smaller number than. That's why.

Comment: It might only confuse things even more, but there is a similar question about the English word too: [etymology - How did the word "important" come to mean "significant" - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463514/how-did-the-word-important-come-to-mean-significant). ¶  Briefly, the original Latin word meant to bring in or import something. From there, "importance" was a measure of the value of what was brought in, and from there it became a count of what was being talked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/important) says :

> Qui atteint un niveau dont on juge qu'il est grand.

which is exactly the meaning the adjective has in the sentence you quote.

The definition in [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/important) has the same:

> Considérable.

It is quite usual to use *important* when estimating population:

> les Vosges concentrent une population importante d’agriculteurs. ([www.interieur.gouv.fr](http://www.interieur.gouv.fr))

> le littoral métropolitain a une densité de population importante ([Un document de l'Observatoire national de la mer et du littoral](http://www.dirm.mediterranee.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/les_donnees_cles_de_la_mer_et_du_littoral_onml.pdf))

It is also quite usual to have the adjective in the comparative or superlative:

> La population des Premières Nations représente la plus importante population autochtone au Canada. ([Document de l'Unicef](http://ccnsa.ca/docs/nccah%20partner%20documents/UNICEF%20report%20-%20French%2009.pdf))

> il est clair qu'une population plus importante contribue au dynamisme de l'économie. ([Débats du Parlement européen](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/CRE-5-2003-02-11_FR.html?redirect))

> il faut en premier lieu déterminer s'il sera nécessaire de faire des énoncés globaux ou généraux sur une population plus importante. ([Bureau du vérificateur général du Canada](https://www.oag-bvg.gc.ca/internet/Francais/meth_gde_f_19724.html))

> Aujourd'hui, l'Union européenne élargie présente une population plus importante que celle des États-Unis. ([Débats du Parlement européen](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/CRE-5-2003-04-09_FR.html?redirect))

> Si les États-Unis, avec une population bien plus importante que la nôtre, peuvent le faire, nous devrions quand même en être capables aussi au Canada. ([Débats du Parlement du Canada](https://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/40-2/chambre/seance-32/debats))

Comment: Sans doute le sens s'est-il dilué progressivement de "particulièrement grand" ou "assez grand pour être considéré" à juste "grand"/"numériquement grand".